# Error when trying to change the player's orientation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float mainCameraRotateY;

    void Update()
    {
        mainCameraRotateY = Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles.y;

        if (Input.GetButton("Vertical") || Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))
        {
            Debug.Log(this.transform.eulerAngles.y);
            Debug.Log(mainCameraRotateY);
            this.transform.eulerAngles.y = mainCameraRotateY;
        }
    }
}
```

The above is a script attached to the player to make the player turn to the direction the camera is looking at when moving.

But an error was reported with `this.transform.eulerAngles.y = mainCameraRotateY;`

> error CS1612: Cannot modify the return value of
> 'Transform.eulerAngles' because it is not a variable

All other parts can operate normally.

How can i fix this?

Comment: A simple google search would've given you this: https://forum.unity.com/threads/cannot-modify-because-it-is-not-a-variable-in-c.6404/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var eulerAngles = this.transform.eulerAngles;
eulerAngles.y = mainCameraRotateY;
this.transform.eulerAngles = eulerAngles;
```

You can't change `this.transform.eulerAngles` directly because it is internally implemented as a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties), not a variable. Because the internal Unity code likely implements a custom setter function, the whole object needs to be assigned at once and individual sub-variables or sub-properties cannot be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn‘t realize that it is a property. And sorry I forgot that I should use a search engine first. I will use google first next time

Answer (score 1):

[`Transform.eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) is a [**property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) which either returns or takes a complete [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) which is a [`struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) and thereby a **value** type.

This means even if it *would* compile, it would have no effect since you *would* only be changing the `y` component of a **returned** vector and then immediately throw it away.

In order to change the `Transform.eulerAngles` you have to actually assign a complete `Vector3` to it.

If you want to change a single component of it you have to do it like e.g.

```
var eulerAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
eulerAngles.y = mainCameraRotateY;
transform.eulerAngles = eulerAngles;
```